# Timer triggers with host storage locks using IAzureClientFactory

Tags: .net, azure, azure-webjobssdk

I am running a standalone application and using the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs` SDK. I am currently using `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage` (v 5.0.0) and a `TimeTrigger`. To inject Azure SDK clients I usually use `Microsoft.Extensions.Azure` integration as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/microsoft.extensions.azure-readme?view=azure-dotnet) which lets me inject named clients and control the `TokenCredential` used for each client. I want to connect to the host storage with my injected client, but it seems the package isn't actually using it, instead it uses the `DefaultAzureCredential` (trying VS credentials, Managed Identity credentials, etc).

Is there a way to make `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage` resolve the blob service provider for the host storage through the injected `IAzureClientFactory`?

Program.cs:

```
hostBuilder.ConfigureWebJobs(serviceBuilder =>
{
    serviceBuilder.Services.AddAzureClients(builder =>
    {
        builder.AddClient<BlobServiceClient, BlobClientOptions>((options, credentials, serviceProvider) =>
        {
            TokenCredential tokenCredential = new MyTokenCredential();

            return new BlobServiceClient(new Uri("https://<my-storage>.blob.core.windows.net"), credential: tokenCredential, options);
        });
    });

    serviceBuilder.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
    serviceBuilder.AddTimers();
});
```

MyTokenCredential.cs:

```
public class MyTokenCredential : TokenCredential
{
    public override AccessToken GetToken(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test1");

        return default;
    }

    public override ValueTask<AccessToken> GetTokenAsync(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test2");

        return default;
    }
}
```

Function.cs:

```
public async Task Invoke5MinFlowJobsAsync([TimerTrigger("00:05:00", RunOnStartup = false)] TimerInfo timerInfo)
{
    await _service.DoSomethingAsync("5 min");
}
```

appsettings.json:

```
"AzureWebJobsStorage": {
  "blobServiceUri": "https://<my-storage>.blob.core.windows.net"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're attempting to incorporate a custom token credential to access Azure Storage within your Azure Functions application using the **`IAzureClientFactory`**. However, the **`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage`** package doesn't directly facilitate this approach for authentication. Instead, it depends on the **`AzureWebJobsStorage`** setting from **appsettings.json** or **local.settings.json** to configure the storage connection.

***You can add this setting -**`AzureWebJobsStorage:"connectionstring"`** in Azure Web app Environment Variables.***

***Function Timer Trigger code:-***

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

namespace FunctionApp2
{
    public class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

            string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage");
            string containerName = "data";
            string blobName = "Test.txt";

            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

            BlobDownloadInfo download = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await download.Content.CopyToAsync(ms);
                string blobContent = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                log.LogInformation($"Blob content: {blobContent}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

My **`local.settings.json`**:-

```json
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=siliconstrg54;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxx3/TWrxxxxfaw==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't want my actual triggered function to access storage, I want the host itself to access the storage (for the lock blobs to sync the time triggers). I am trying to do it with my own TokenCredential to reduce the use of secrets

Comment: using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Core;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

Comment: namespace FunctionApp2
{
    public class MyTokenCredential : TokenCredential
    {
        public override AccessToken GetToken(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Implement your logic to retrieve the access token
            // For example:
            string accessToken = "<your_access_token_here>";
            DateTimeOffset expiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1); // Set expiration time
            return new AccessToken(accessToken, expiresOn);
        }

Comment: public override ValueTask<AccessToken> GetTokenAsync(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Implement your async logic to retrieve the access token
            // For example:
            string accessToken = "<your_access_token_here>";
            DateTimeOffset expiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1); // Set expiration time
            return new ValueTask<AccessToken>(new AccessToken(accessToken, expiresOn));
        }
    }

Comment: public class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

            string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage");
            string containerName = "data";
            string blobName = "Test.txt";

            // Create your custom token credential
            TokenCredential tokenCredential = new MyTokenCredential();

Comment: // Use the token credential with the BlobServiceClient constructor

Comment: Again, this is not what I am trying to do (see my previous comment)